# Get current URL address from IE using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I'm trying to automate a process in my Service Desk job where we have to copy the client's details from the intranet, we have to select just their username from their email and copy their phone number etc from a diff. part of the page (i.e. diff HTML tags on the same page).

I'm playing around with powershell and am able to extract some information by parsing the html but I have to manually add the URL in the Invoke -Webrequest query.

Is there a way in Powershell to fetch the address of the url currently open in IE? The thing is that the URL always changes as we search for diff user.

An example would be "www.intranet/user1" or "www.intranet/user3" etc.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Comment: I want to confirm with you whether the sample code I provided in my reply helps you to get the desired result? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Yes Deepak, your answer helps.

Comment: Hey Deepak, how do I save the locationURL to a variable so that I can parse the HTML later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you had asked, **Is there a way in Powershell to fetch the address of the url currently open in IE?**

You can refer to an example below.

```
$ShellWindows = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows()
($shellwindows | ? {$_.locationurl -like "http*"}).locationURL
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your requirements.