# How to intercept captive portal URL via powershell?

Tags: powershell, packet-sniffers, packet-capture, captiveportal, captivenetwork

When connecting to a walled-garden network (e.g. free airport wifi), the network usually automatically opens the URL to its captive portal in the browser. How would one intercept this URL with Powershell?

Background: I use DNScrypt-Proxy to encrypt my DNS traffic, but it often breaks captive portal requests. I'm writing a Powershell script to detect when my computer is trying to connect to a walled-garden network and temporarily disable DNScrypt-proxy to allow the portal request through. I'd actually like to open the Captive Portal URL in a non-default browser window, and to do this programmatically, I'd need to be able to intercept* the URL that the network tries to open. (*It's not 100% necessary that the URL *doesn't* go through to my default browser, as I can always close the browser tab. It would just be cleaner if it doesn't.)

I *suspect* this involves packet-sniffing, but I'm really not familiar at all with network-related stuff. Simple solutions, especially those that don't require any external programs like Wireshark, are preferable. Thanks!

EDIT: I've found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353376/9621742) that doesn't *intercept* the request (I don't know what means a captive network even uses to tell the default browser to open the URL, so I don't even know where to start investigating it), but supposedly it fetches the URLs of currently open tabs, which would suffice. It didn't work when I tried it, though, and I have no idea why. (Note: I'm running Firefox on Windows 10.)

```
$ShellWindows = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows()
($shellwindows | ? {$_.locationurl -like "http*"}).locationURL
```

Comment: This is, of necessity, a programmer's Q&A site. With that said, what does your code look like so far? (If it's not a programming/code question but a theoretical question, perhaps your question is more appropriate for superuser.com?)

Comment: Nothing theoretical about it. I want to write a powershell script. I need to know what commands, cmdlets, modules, etc I would need to call to get this job done (if it's even possible via powershell). I don't have any code to share because this is step 1. If it's not possible to intercept the URL, then the whole project falls apart.

Comment: It becomes a lot less theoretical when you include the code you have already tried, and the specific researching that you have attempted that has not yielded results. (Otherwise, it sounds a bit like you are asking others to do the research and write the code for you.)

Comment: My apologies, I hadn't realized posting to a forum would coerce strangers into doing research for me. I had naively assumed that people with helpful information would share it, while people without any knowledge relevant to the question would simply move on.

Comment: Well, as noted previously, this site isn't a forum but rather a place to ask specific and focused programming questions. Your question is very exploratory and non-specific, unfortunately, so it's not really a great fit for this particular site. It might be a better fit on superuser.com (or the like).